# css to scss migration - how to integrate css files included via npm modules?

Tags: css, npm, sass

Am new to SASS and am trying to change css files to scss in my existing project. I understand that changing the extension to .scss will do for my custom files but am unsure about how to proceed with the dependency style files. I use npm to install my dependencies and some of them do not come with .scss files. What is the correct approach to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the dependencies to SCSS. Just import the CSS files as they are and they'll work!

Think of SCSS as just an extension of CSS rather than something totally different!